# jqGrid not load using @Transactional

Tags: java, spring, jqgrid, struts2, mybatis

When I add the annotation `@Transactional` in method of cap business, `jqGrid` doesn't load data. But less annotation works fine, Why?

```
@Service
@Scope("request")
public class MarcacionServiceImp implements MarcacionService{

@Autowired
MarcacionMapper mapper;

@Transactional  
public List<Marcacion> lista() throws Exception {
    List<Marcacion> lista = mapper.listado();
    return lista;
}

 }

<action name="cargarMarcacion" class="cargaMarcacionAction">
        <result type="json" />
</action>


<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="/WEB-INF/mybatis-config.xml" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" 
       class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
    p:driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" p:url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/asistencia"
    p:username="root" p:password="root" />

<bean id="transactionManager"     
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager"
  p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" />

<bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
    <property name="basePackage" value="mapper" />
    <property name="sqlSessionFactoryBeanName" value="sqlSessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="usuarioAction" class="action.UsuarioAction" >
    <property name="service" ref="usuarioService" />    
</bean>  
<bean id="usuarioService" class="negocio.UsuarioServiceImp" />

<bean id="cargaMarcacionAction" class="action.CargaMarcacionAction">
    <property name="service" ref="marcacionService" />
</bean> 
<bean id="marcacionService" class="negocio.MarcacionServiceImp" />
```

Not get JSON data in my page. I am using Struts2-Spring and MyBatis-Spring.
I mean that problem is `@Transactional` not return my JSON data.

Comment: I think it has nothing to do with jqgrid. Write an integration test and see if you are able to fetch data using lista method.

Comment: Yes, I get data from method lista. I suppose that spring blocks json from server...

Comment: How do u return json from Spring?

Comment: I don't know. I use ActionSupport.

Comment: Is there a json ouput shown in your browser debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When struts2 return `"json"` result by default it's configured to serialize the action instance itself. But I think it's not needed for the `jqGrid` and it requires only the relevant data. You could use the parameters of the `"json"` result to narrow properties required for serialization. First, you should define a property getter by renaming a method which return data for serialization.

```
@Transactional  
public List<Marcacion> getLista() throws Exception {
    List<Marcacion> lista = mapper.listado();
    return lista;
}
```

Second, add the `"root"` parameter to the result

```
<result type="json">
  <param name="root">lista</param>
</result>
```

`@Transactional` is not related to the JSON data serialization but it requires if you retrieve data from the database.

Comment: If I want serialization of more objects only I have delimited with commas? For Example:  <param name="root">lista,someBean,map</param>

Comment: No, you should choose root object that contain those properties and then use `includeProperties` or `excludeProperties` to specify which properties should be included or excluded from serialization process.